# WPF Colour Picker/Wheel with Multiple Selection

Tags: wpf, color-picker, color-wheel

I am looking for a free WPF Colour Picker/Wheel which has the ability to allow multiple colour selections. Does anything like this exist. The ones I have seen allow only one colour to be selected. I want to be able to easily select two or three colors.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `color wheel for silverlight` (you can adapt it for wpf): http://asyrovprog.host22.com/colorwheel.html. Source code is located here: [timeline.codeplex.com](http://timeline.codeplex.com).